# php usort error message

Tags: php, usort

I have a class called Link with a function called Compare. When I runt this code I keep getting an error message

```
foreach($filearray as $k=>$v)  
{  
$website = new Link($v);  
$links[] = $website;  
}  
usort($links, array("Link","compare"));
```

But I get an error message and I cant figure out why...

> "Warning: usort() [function.usort]: The argument should be an array"

Comment: That's an odd issue. Does `var_dump($links);` actually return an array?

Comment: Are you sure that the foreach loop are actual executed?

Answer (score 3):

If `$links` haven't been initialized as an array, when `$filearray` is empty, `$links` remains `null`.

Add `$links = array();` before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter is the comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Check the below article
http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php